# git reset --soft seems to change index

Tags: git, git-reset

Having read through [Mark Dominus's article](http://blog.plover.com/prog/git-reset.html) and [Scott Chanon's article](http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html) I assumed that `git reset abcd --soft` would not affect the index, however, the following shows that it does.

## Before Reset

`c1.txt`, `c2.txt`, `c3.txt` in the repo, `c4.txt` in the index.  All in the working directory:

### History:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate
b91d91b (HEAD, master) C3
231a5df C2
7e7b2d7 C1
```

### The index:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   c4.txt
```

### The working directory:

```
$ ls
c1.txt  c2.txt  c3.txt  c4.txt
```

### Reset softly to the C2 commit

```
$ git reset 231a --soft

$ git log --oneline --decorate
231a5df (HEAD, master) C2
7e7b2d7 C1
```

### Index has changed

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   c3.txt
        new file:   c4.txt


$ ls
c1.txt  c2.txt  c3.txt  c4.txt
```

### What I thought would happen

From Scott's article, he says:

> The first thing reset will do is move what HEAD points to.... If you add the flag --soft, this is the only thing it will do. With --soft, reset will simply stop there.

So, I thought that the index (which I hope I've understood to be what's shown in the `git status` outputs above) would not change, that being, it would still contain `c4.txt`.  The output above shows that it actually contains `c3.txt` and `c4.txt`.

It appears that `c3.txt` has been moved into the index alongside `c4.txt`.

Comment: "however, the following shows that it does" -- No, it doesn't, and quite frankly, I'm having a hard time understanding why you think it does. Can you explain in a bit more detail? (Remember that the fact that the index doesn't change means that if it was equal to the old commit tree, and the old commit tree and new commit tree are different, then the index can't be equal to the new commit tree.)

Comment: I'm assuming it's something I've not understood, I'll add some more the the question.

Comment: You should have provided all the git commands to make it really easy to reproduce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental misunderstanding seems to be about what the index *is*. The index isn't a set of differences, it's a set of files. What `git status` shows is not the index, but the difference between the last commit and the index.

Before your `git reset --soft`, the index contained files `c1.txt`, `c2.txt`, `c3.txt` and `c4.txt`. So after your `git reset --soft`, the index still contains those same files. `git status` will report this differently, but that isn't because the index changed, that's because the commit changed.

Comment: OK, so, at the point immediately _after_ a commit, the index is equal to the previous commit.  Therefore, moving backwards, `git status` will report that there are new files in the index, that were not in the previous commit.

Comment: Yes, for commits that simply add files, that's effectively the result.

Comment: That's the missing link.  It makes sense now.

Comment: What command shows the index then?  Let's say I do a commit, I always thought that clears the index, since git status -s shows it as clear, but perhaps the index isn't clear and it's just that there are no files in the index that aren't also in the commit. So, perhaps a commit clears the index, but what command would shoe me that? it seems git status -s wouldn't.

Comment: @barlop `git ls-files` shows which files are in the index.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the git docs:

> Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all (but resets the head to , just like all modes do). **This leaves all your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put it.**

This means that your commit will be removed but only to "Changes to be committed". So you have to run `git reset <file>` again to remove them completely. For future commits you may want the `--mixed` mode (`git reset --mixed 231a`). Docs:

> Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., **the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit**) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to understand what it does with `--soft`, `--mixed` and `--hard`.  The behaviour I expected isn't what I'd understood it to be.

Comment: Keep in mind that the index is just a list of pathname-indexed content. When you `git add` you put the added content into the repository, and git updates the index to say that now that's the content you've got so far that goes with that path.  The current commit aka `HEAD` is a little file with the id or a reference to a branch that has the id of a commit.  `git reset --soft` changes that id, and nothing else. `git reset --mixed` changes the id and reloads the index from the new commit -- so differences now are between your worktree and the indexed content (and naturally also the head commit)